# Problem filtering SOAP API product.list with store ID

Tags: magento-enterprise, api, soap

We are trying to retreive product details for a specific SKU and for a specific store by using the Magento SOAP API with the product.list method.

We can retrieve product details but they are defaulting to the default store and not the store ID that we are trying to filter by.

**Here is the code:**

```
$filters = array (
  'sku' => array('eq' => 'ABC')
);

// Then we have tried both of the following which only show product information for the default store and not store ID 38

$products = $soap->call($session_id, 'product.list', $filters, '38');

$products = $soap->call($session_id, 'product.list', array($filters, '38');
```

**Edit! - I've fixed it**

```
$args = array(
    'productId' => '7745-XXL',
    'storeView' => 'pr_de_main_store'
);

$product = $soap->call( $session_id, 'catalog_product.info', $args);
```

Thanks!

Anthony

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$args = array(
    'productId' => '7745-XXL',
    'storeView' => 'pr_de_main_store'
);

$product = $soap->call( $session_id, 'catalog_product.info', $args);
```

Comment: Not working, whereas the code from "Smile" works.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution and it works:

```
$filters = array (
  'sku' => array('eq' => 'ABC')
);
$soap->call($session_id, 'product.list', array($filters, 'store_code'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the store code, instead of the ID.

E.g. `$products = $soap->call($session_id, 'product.list', $filters, 'my_store_de');`

Comment: Hi, I've tried with the store code and it still returns the default store product details. :(

$filters = array (
  'sku' => array('=' => '7745-XXL')
 );
 
    $product = $soap->call( $session_id, 'product.list', array($filters), 'pr_de_main_store');
 
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($product); // Gives me default store product details
 echo "</pre>";